# Remote URL for polymorphic association (Carrierwave)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have a `Post` model, with a polymorphic association with `Attachment` (`as: :attachable`).

I'm wanting to systematically add a remote url attachment to a `Post`. IF the attachment were not polymorphic, this would work perfectly...

`@post.remote_filename_url = 'http://example.com/file.jpg'`

However, that doesn't work because it needs to be along these lines (although this doesn't work either...), but just to give you an idea of hopefully what I'm trying to do:

`@post.remote_attachable_filename_uri = 'http://example.com/jpg'`

Thanks! (PS... I'm doing all this through console/a helper lib. None of this is via forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Attachment is the model with `mount_uploader :filename` (not Post), then you should just be calling `@attachment.remote_filename_url=`. Carrierwave doesn't know or care about your model relationships.

Answer (score 0):

`@post.attachments.create(remote_WHATEVER_url: 'http://url.to/remote.file')`